# Getting error 1064 while running query for table creation?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I already have created customers and products table.I am getting this error while running following command in phpmyadmin.
`CREATE TABLE orders (    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    orderNumber INT,
    productId INT,
    customerId INT,
    orderDate DATETIME default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (customerId) REFERENCES customers(id) ,
    FOREIGN KEY (productId) REFERENCES products(id)
                    );`

[1064 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOzHJ.png)

Comment: I think you are trying to create a `Foreign Key`, but you stated `PRIMARY KEY (customerId) REFERENCES customers(id)`. Correct the second to last line. Change to `FOREIGN KEY`

Comment: yEAH you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Can not create more than one primary keys.

Try this code.

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
orderNumber INT,
productId INT,
customerId INT,
orderDate DATETIME default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
FOREIGN  KEY (customerId) REFERENCES customers(id) ,
FOREIGN KEY (productId) REFERENCES products(id));
```

Comment: you id INT(5) ? but the  error seems to be in last two lines

Comment: See my comment above. Can't create 2 Primary Keys. I think the second to last line is supposed to be a Foreign Key.

Comment: Yes, can't create more than one primary keys.

Comment: YOU are late bro :p @sameera

Comment: @pratyush choudhary ok, but I think you will agree with my answer. Can u accept my answer if it's correct.